# Printing multipe PDFs from EXCEL into one file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have this code. It cycles thru and changes a value, then prints, and repeats. Issue is, my pdf is only of the last cycle value, its not adding each change as a separate sheet in my pdf.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()



For x = 1 To 100 'increase the 100 to a larger number if you ever have more than 100 sheets

If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("T" & x).Value = "" Then Exit Sub

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F4").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("T" & x).Value

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F3").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("U" & x).Value

'For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF

                               

Next

End Sub
```

Tried the code, expected a pdf with 20 sheets, but only got 1, the last value of my range.

Comment: You are missing the part that names your pdf Link to [exportPDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat)

Comment: Name is optional, it just saves in the folder with the spreadsheet. It is only the last value of the range defined. I want it to be every value of the range.

Comment: I added a path, still only printing the last set of the range to the pdf.

Comment: Yes I see you have changed your explanations in other forums.

Comment: I have been trying to get it to work. I am trying to explain it better, but obviously its stumped everyone, lol.

Comment: What would u suggest?

Comment: I got an answer from the microsoft types.

Answer (score 0):

This works for what I want.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For x = 1 To 100 'increase the 100 to a larger number if you ever have more than 100 sheets

If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("T" & x).Value = "" Then Exit Sub

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F4").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("T" & x).Value

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F3").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("U" & x).Value

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test" & x & ".pdf"

Next

End Sub
```